# Passing JSON data to WCF (.Net 4) Web Service

Tags: wcf, json

I have a very simple [OperationContract] called TestClass that gets called like this:

```
var person = { "Name": "Dave", "City":"HB", "State": "CA", "Zip":"92649" };

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(person),                   
                url: "MyService.svc/TestClass",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#output").text("[ " + data + "]");
                }
            });
```

What I'm not understanding, and can't seem to find, is the preferred way of using these services. I've been searching everywhere for the past few days and I feel really overwhelmed with what I've found so far.  I read one post where somebody said not to use Message but to create their own DataContract which I tried.

Here is my Operation Contract:

```
 [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public Message TestClass(Message m)
    { return WebOperationContext.Current.CreateTextResponse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject("Ok"));}
```

Besides having 4 input values to TestClass, I would prefer just one.  Message is the only thing that seems to work.  I tried using just a string and that value is always null.

I've tried creating a [DataContract] for the data and use that as the parameter in the TestClass call but that also is null.

I'm new to using these service types so any pointers for a beginner is greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**

**IService.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace WcfTest
{
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute()]
    public interface IService
    {
    [System.ServiceModel.Web.WebInvokeAttribute(BodyStyle = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, 
     RequestFormat = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageFormat.Json, 
     ResponseFormat = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageFormat.Json)]

        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute()]
        void ProcessData(RootClass input);
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute()]
    public partial class RootClass
    {
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string Name;
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string City;
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string State;
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string Zip;
    }
}
```

**ServiceZ.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace WcfTest
{
    public class ServiceZ : IService
    {
        public void ProcessData(RootClass input)
        {
            int i = 6;      // used for a breakpoint
        }
    }
}
```

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/json2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $().ready(function () {
            var person = { "Name": "Dave", "City": "HB", "State": "CA", "Zip": "92649" };

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(person),
                url: "ServiceZ.svc/ProcessData",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#output").text("OK!");
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    debugger;
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="output" style="background: lightgreen;">--></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Try to use custom contract with correctly named properties (according to your JSON) and add `BodyStyle = MessageBodyStyle.Bare` to your `WebInvoke` attribute.

Comment: Thank you Ladislav, but when I add the BodyStyle attribute, I get an error 500.

Comment: Turn on WCF tracing and find the reason for the error: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx

Comment: Lots of info returned.  
Exception Type: System.NullReferenceException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a the data contract for your data. The tool at http://carlosfigueira.me/JsonUtilities/JsonToContract.htm (more information about it at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/01/11/inferring-schemas-for-json.aspx) can give you a data contract which is compatible with the JSON data. By running it with your input I got the code below.

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:v4.0.30319
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute()]
public interface IService
{
    [System.ServiceModel.Web.WebInvokeAttribute(BodyStyle = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute()]
    void ProcessData(RootClass input);
}

[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute()]
public partial class RootClass
{

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public string Name;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public string City;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public string State;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public string Zip;
}
```

**Update**: I created a new project (empty web application), and added the following files - the client received the correct response. Try comparing with what you have to see if there is anything different. And the 415 error you're getting usually indicates which you don't have the appropriate binding / behavior on this endpoint. To enable REST endpoints (which can accept JSON), the endpoint needs to have the `webHttpBinding` and a behavior with the `<webHttp/>` on it. Or another alternative (which is what I used) is to use the `WebServiceHostFactory` on the .svc file, in which case you don't need anything on web.config.

**ServiceZ.svc**

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true"
    Service="StackOverflow_7141298.ServiceZ"
    CodeBehind="ServiceZ.svc.cs"
    Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory" %>
```

**IServiceZ.cs**

```
namespace StackOverflow_7141298
{
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute()]
    public interface IService
    {
        [System.ServiceModel.Web.WebInvokeAttribute(BodyStyle = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute()]
        string ProcessData(RootClass input);
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute()]
    public partial class RootClass
    {

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string Name;

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string City;

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string State;

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string Zip;
    }
}
```

**ServiceZ.svc.cs**

```
namespace StackOverflow_7141298
{
    public class ServiceZ : IService
    {
        public string ProcessData(RootClass input)
        {
            if (input == null) return "NULL!!!";
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            return string.Format("Name={0},City={1},State={2},Zip={3}",
                input.Name ?? "<<null>>",
                input.City ?? "<<null>>",
                input.State ?? "<<null>>",
                input.Zip ?? "<<null>>");
        }
    }
}
```

**HTMLPage1.htm**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="json2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $().ready(function () {
            var person = { "Name": "Dave", "City": "HB", "State": "CA", "Zip": "92649" };

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(person),
                url: "ServiceZ.svc/ProcessData",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#output").text(data);
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    //debugger;
                    $("#output").text("Error!");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Carlos.  I tried to implement what you suggested and I still get an error.  Error #500.  I included all the code back in the orinial question.  Do you see anything wrong with what added?  AHHHHH!  Thank you!

Comment: A few things to try: can you browse to the .svc file? When you enable tracing, what is the error you get on the traces (you mentioned a NullReferenceException, what's the call stack of that error)?

Comment: Thanks again Carlos.  If I type http://localhost:3782/Service.svc, I do get a page that the service is there (I renamed it back to Service).  It suggests I use svcutil to create a client class.  Now I seem to be getting error 415 "Unsupported Media Type".  Why can't this be easy?  I even started with a brand new project to test this.

Comment: I updated the response with a complete example. The 415 error I think it's because you have an incorrect endpoint binding/behavior configuration.

Comment: Carlos, thank you so much.  I think the big difference was the Factory in the SVC file.  I did everything you did, byte by byte, and this works.  I took the Factory out of the SVC file and it didn't.  You are a life-saver.  Thank you so much for taking time out of your schedule to help me.  I really appreciate it :)