# Wcf service (ajax enabled) passed XML child object is always null

Tags: c#, ajax, wcf, xml-deserialization

I have a WCF (ajax enabled) web service, and have the following method, that accepts a object called TypeRequest.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/XML/GetTypes", 
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]

XElement XMLGetTypes(TypeRequest obj) 
{  
  //do something 
}
```

The TypeRequest object is defined as;

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class TypeRequest 
{
    [Required]
    [DataMember]
    public long Id{ get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataMember]
    public Account Account { get; set; }
}
```

Then my child Account class is as follows;

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class Account
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Email address
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(175)]        
    public string Email { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Plain text password
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(16, MinimumLength = 8)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

The problem I have is that if I make the call passing the following sample Xml

```
<TypeRequest>
<Id>1</Id>
<Account>
<Email>myemail@domain.com</Email>
<Password>12345</Password>
</Account>
</TypeRequest>
```

to the method XMLGetTypes(TypeRequest obj), I can view the obj and Id has the correct value, but the Account object is null

Why is this, what am I doing wrong as I can't seem to figure it out.  Do I need to provide anymore information to get some help ?

Further to my previous information, I have added a method for accepting JSON requests like

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/JSON/GetTypes", 
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]

string JSONGetTypes(TypeRequest obj) 
{  
  //do something 
}
```

Calling this with the JSON as

```
{
  "TypeRequest": {
    "Id": "1",
    "Account": {
      "Email": "myemail@domain.com",
      "Password": "12345"
    }
  }
}
```

I can view the TypeRequest obj, and can view all the correct data that was posted.   Therefore, why isn't the Xml post working ?!?

Comment: Do I need to provide any more information to get some responses..?

Comment: I think `[StringLength(16, MinimumLength = 8)]` and your length of password is only 5 that can be case give it try

Comment: Tried removing '[StringLength(16, MinimumLength = 8)]' but still doesn't work.  The account object is null

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7142948/2630817 Have u checked this?

Comment: JSON request and response works.  It is when I pass the equivalent XML that is null

Comment: No both Methods are diff `[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]` Check for this

Comment: I checked but still the same.... Like I said JSON requests are file, if I pass XML request I can read the value in Id, but the account object is NULL

Comment: Why you can not differentiate both the things?

Comment: @DholakiyaAnkit I tried what you suggested but still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding

> [XmlSerializerFormat] to my method solved the problem.  For example

```
[OperationContract]
[XmlSerializerFormat]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/XML/GetTypes", 
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]

XElement XMLGetTypes(TypeRequest obj) 
{  
  //do something 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your xml to this?

```
<TypeRequest>
  <Id>1</Id>
  <Account>
    <Email>myemail@domain.com</Email>
    <Password>12345</Password>
</TypeRequest>
```

Comment: Sorry, I omitted the <Account> and </Account> tags which I've now included in my question, but still I can't see the data in the Account object.  Any ideas why.

Comment: Hmm, no good idea. I guess one thing you could try in a test is using an XmlSerializer to take in an instance of your TypeRequest object and output the xml. Then copy that xml and send it to your service. I have no reason to think the xml that is generated would be any different than what you have provided, but it might be.

Comment: Anything else I can try ??